# Places on Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

If we have an algebraic curve $C$, I am wondering what are the *places of $C$*?

I've seen many different definitions, but I don't understand what would that be in essence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb{C}[x]$ is the coordinate ring of $\Bbb{A^1_C}$. Its maximal ideals are the principal ideals $(x-a)$ for each $a\in \Bbb{C}$, each of them induces a discrete valuation $v_a((x-a)^k f(x))= k$ for $f(x)\in \Bbb{C}[x],f(x)\not \in (x-a)$, and a discrete valuation ring $O_{v_a} = \{ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\in \Bbb{C}(x),f(x),g(x)\in \Bbb{C}[x], v_a(f) \ge v_a(g)\}$.

For an element of the function field $\Bbb{C}(x)$, $v_a(f(x))$ is telling the order of the zero/pole of $f(x)$ at $a$.

It works the same way for the other kind of smooth affine curves, except that often the maximal ideal becomes principal only in the localization $(R-\mathfrak{m})^{-1}R$, which is then a DVR. Smooth is to ensure the localization at maximal ideals of the coordinate ring are DVR. A place means the data of a maximal ideal plus its DVR plus its discrete valuation plus an uniformizer (a generator of the maximal ideal).

There are a few DVR that are not obtained from the maximal ideals of the coordinate ring, in the case of $\Bbb{A^1_C}$ it is the one obtained from the maximal ideal $(x^{-1})$ of $\Bbb{C}[x^{-1}]$. When adding the few missed DVR we obtain a complete smooth curve which corresponds to a smooth projective curve.